# Trying to acquire the parent's class of an element using JQuery

Tags: jquery, parent-child

So I have acquired the element I want, but I want to check the elements parent class value to verify it is a certain value before doing my logic and I can't quite figure it out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#childElement input').click(function() {
        var option = $(this).parent('span').class;
        alert(option.class);
        if (option == 'left') {
            //some action
        }
});
```

The HTML is:

```
<span class="left">
<input type="checkbox" tabindex="401"><label>some verbage</label></span>
```

I am able to fire on the checking off of the checkbox, but I want to acquire the 'class' value of the span element (which i believe is the input element's parent.  Then do an if comparison to check if class == "left".

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to remove the option.class from the alert to just alert(option).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check using [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), like this:

```
if($(this).parent('span').hasClass('left')) {
```

Or use a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
if($(this).parent('span.left').length) {
```

To get the `class` like you were attempting, it would be [`.attr('class')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of `.class` :)

Comment: Also, `$(this).parent('span')[0].className;` :)

Comment: @pghtech - Did that resolve it, or are you still having issues? :)

Comment: That resolved it.  I couldn't select an answer until a period of time had passed.